# Ability to get service request from any platform

Tags: wcf

I wrote some WCF service. 
I used basicHttp and i need to have the ability to give the service to any platform.

I check my service with simple winform client application and i also checked this using some silverlight client application that i wrote => and its look fine - work well.

But do i need to change something in my config file to have the ability to have Android / IPhone platform client that will call my service using simple basice http protocol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `basicHttpBinding` produces a standard SOAP 1.2 web service that any client should be able to consume.